# In vb.net, how do I convert this number 1421165664.0892897 to date time?

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net,

how do I convert this number 1421165664.0892897 to date time?

Its a Unix timestamp.

Is there a date function to do this?

Comment: where did the value come from?

Comment: We would need to know what that number represents before we can tell you how to convert it.  Is it Seconds Past Midnight of January 1, 0001?  Is it based on the Unix Epoch?

Comment: Its a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Use NodaTime: http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_Instant_FromSecondsSinceUnixEpoch.htm

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [here:](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-.net-datetime.aspx)

```
static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
}
```

In other words unix time is seconds since 1970-01-01 0:0:0, so start at that time in .NET, and add the seconds.

Comment: It comes back as   #1/13/2015 4:14:24 PM# . Anyway to get rid of the surrounding # signs?

Comment: @user3020047 it does NOT come back as #1/13/2015 4:14:24 PM#, it comes back as a DateTime (which is a structure containing a number). The format with the # signs is just how the debugger displays it. If you want to display it to the user, use the ToString Method of DateTime and specify what format you want, or use the ToLongDateString or ToShortDateString methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Public Shared Function UnixTimeStampToDateTime(unixTimeStamp As Double) As DateTime
    ' Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    Dim dtDateTime As System.DateTime = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, _
        0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc)
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime()
    Return dtDateTime
End Function
```

Comment: It comes back as   #1/13/2015 4:14:24 PM# . Anyway to get rid of the surrounding # signs?

Comment: How are you getting that printed representation?  Use the [ToString() overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a formatting string parameter, and give it a suitable [formatting string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I pass the function the double and i take the datetime passed back and assign it to a datetime field in a structure that I have. In the debugger I look at the structure and I see it surrounded by the #'s.

Comment: The string overload and formatting did not change it. The structure file is defined as Dim last_flow_time As DateTime....and the command is:    dtLastFlowTime = UnixTimestampToDateTime(strValues(1))
                    last_flow_time = dtLastFlowTime.ToString("g")

Comment: There's something you're not telling me.

Comment: Whatever representation you are seeing in the debugger does not matter.  The printed representation will still apply.